# ParseFromString function of protobuf returns false

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

This is my code:

```
static bool hget(acl::redis_hash& redis,char *key,char *attr){

nrtprofile::RedisNewsMessage redisNewsMessage;
acl::string value;
if(redis.hget(key,attr,value)==true){
    printf("key: %s, attr: %s, value: %s\n",key,attr,value.c_str());
    if(redisNewsMessage.ParseFromString(value.c_str())) {
        printf("decoded");
    }else{
        printf("try again");
    }

    return true;
}else{
    printf("incorrect key");    
    return false;
}
```

}

I am getting the value correctly after using hget command of redis. But my message is not getting decoded.

When I tried decoding with python it worked perfectly fine. So the encoding is done properly. Why am I not able to decode in c++

Comment: I saw a bug in Protobuf 3 where ParseFromString was returning false even when it had parsed the object correctly. 

I would suggest you ignore the return code and check the object itself for validity.

Comment: @RichardHodges when I am seeing the object it is having size 0 for every map in it

Comment: Is the way I am sending the value to ParseFromString correct?

Comment: I can't tell Nitika. There is not enough code here for me to reproduce. Perhaps set up a very small test? (i.e. provide the .proto file, provide a file containing the binary representation and provide code to parse it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string provided to `ParseFromString` is not a character string. It is an array of arbitrary bytes, including NULs. C++ strings can contain any byte, incliding NULs. C strings cannot; the first NUL terminates the string.

So the use of the `c_str()` interface is incorrect; you need to turn the `acl::string` into a `std::string` without going through a C string. As a side note, using a C++ API which defines its own string class strikes me as a bad idea, because it prevents interoperability. But there might be some appropriate interface.

Answer (score 2):

From the function prototypes I have seen of `ParseFromString`, it takes `string` or reference to `string` as a parameter. It does not take the C string equivalent derived from the `string` as a parameter.

So instead of:

```
if(redisNewsMessage.ParseFromString(value.c_str()))
```

try:

```
if(redisNewsMessage.ParseFromString(value))
```

or

```
if(redisNewsMessage.ParseFromString(&value))
```

Comment: This is actually a very good point. The binary stream may well contain a zero. It has been wrongly downvoted.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHodges. The down-voter did not even mention the reason for the down-vote.